# If I purchase a second online pass, can we use both discs to play multiplayer together?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-360

*Mass Effect 3* has two discs and I know multiplayer works on both. I also have two Xbox 360s.

If I purchase a second multiplayer online pass, could we each use a disc to play multiplayer together (provided that we have separate online passes)? And how much is an Xbox 360 *Mass Effect 3* online multiplayer pass?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My husband and I do this very thing, so yes it works.

To clarify and restate, I bought one copy of the game and used the online code for my gamertag.  My husband bought an online code for 800 MS Points ($10) with his gamertag.

I use one of the game's discs and he uses the other.  We play multiplayer with no issues whatsoever.

You have to purchase the extra online code by booting up the game with a gamertag that doesn't currently have the multiplayer unlocked.  Select multiplayer and follow the onscreen instructions there.  You can't buy it from Xbox.com or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find the Online pass on the xbox [site](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Mass-Effect-3/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8024541095d?nosplash=1&page=1) so i can only guess that when it appears it will be 800 MS points.

I think the method you have said will work, however not many people would think of that, and very few of them would put answers for it online, so i don't know if it will 100% work, but the way i see it if you have 2 xboxs, 2 discs (both with multiplayer), 2 accounts and 2 controllers you should be able to play online with both xboxs :)

Answer (score 1):

I activated the passcode that came with Mass Effect 3 on my gamertag BUT on my husband's console. When he signed in to multiplayer it didn't prompt him to purchase one. This means he can play multiplayer without having to purchase a second online pass. We can both play multiplayer at the same time using the 2 discs and save 800 points. 
Happy Days!!

Answer (score 1):

Add on content is licensed to both a console and a gamertag. So, if Player 1 activates his online pass on Console A, then after that point, Player 1  can play on Console B (content is licensed to Player 1, so he can use it on any 360) at the same time as Player 2 is playing on Console A (content is licensed to Console A, so any gamertag can use it on that console)

Answer (score 0):

After an update you cannot play with people using the other disc. Somewhat annoying and pointless of ea to have multiplayer on two discs and then separate the servers for both discs. You will get a title error when trying to connect with someone using the other disc.

Comment: Hi Chris, and welcome to Arqade!  We like to have answers backed up by authoritative and verifiable sources, if possible.  Can you provide a link to the patch notes where this change was implemented?